# Update request - not excepted result

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two databases. I called A and an other B. A is almost the same database than B in structure. 
There is a table called table1 in both databases. table1 is associated with table2 and table3.

It's a little bit long to explicates every thing, I hope showing the case will be enought to understand what I am trying to do! :)

```
UPDATE ccmm_echange1.medicament 
    SET ccmm_echange1.medicament.echange_id = (SELECT ccmm.medicament.echange_id
                FROM ccmm_echange1.forme, ccmm_echange1.dci, ccmm.medicament, ccmm.forme, ccmm.dci
                WHERE ccmm_echange1.forme.libelle_forme = ccmm.forme.libelle_forme
                AND ccmm_echange1.dci.nom_dci = ccmm.dci.nom_dci
                AND ccmm_echange1.medicament.id_forme = ccmm_echange1.forme.id_forme 
                AND ccmm_echange1.medicament.id_dci = ccmm_echange1.dci.id_dci 
                LIMIT 1);
```

When I execute this update, there are in all lines the same value.. Do you know why? I don't understand where I made a mistake..

Comment: Updated table not link to sub query. so sub query result always same

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
UPDATE ccmm_echange1.medicament SET ccmm_echange1.medicament.echange_id = ( SELECT ccmm.medicament.echange_id FROM ccmm.medicament LIMIT 1 );
```

Use some DBA or sql programmer for this work.